# Is it possible to retrieve the gas guzzlers from any APIs?

Tags: solidity, web3js

So what I am trying to get is the top gas spenders, the following websites are displaying the data that I am interested in querying, but cannot find an endpoint for this information, so any knowledge on this much be appreciated.

https://ethgasstation.info/

https://etherscan.io/gastracker

Another question: With the web3 library, can I somehow get additional information regarding a token address, like images/icons?

Comment: You should focus on one issue at a time. For multiple issues, you can open additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

ETH Gas Station has an API available which you can access through [Defi Pulse](https://data.defipulse.com/). You can find the API documentation [here](https://docs.ethgasstation.info/). For the gas price specifically, use the `api/ethgasAPI.json` endpoint, which is described [here](https://docs.ethgasstation.info/gas-price). Note that you do need an API key, but you can get one for free on Defi Pulse.

Comment: that would get me that gas rates, I am looking for top gas spenders, if you see my websites that I listed as an example, you'd see that it is totally different data.